# facebook Xamarin.Auth Activity redirector

Tags: android, facebook, redirect, xamarin.auth

I try to add facebook auth in my Xamarin App (Google already done)

On facebook i add `https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html` as URI for redirection OAuth valid, all my auth parameter is on.

On Xamarin  :

```
public static string AndroidRedirectUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html"
```

in Constants_Facebook class,

On Click :

```
          string clientId = null;
            string redirectUri = null;

            if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
            {
                clientId = Constants_Facebook.iOSClientId;
                redirectUri = Constants_Facebook.iOSRedirectUrl;
            }
            else if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
            {
                clientId = Constants_Facebook.AndroidClientId;
                redirectUri = Constants_Facebook.AndroidRedirectUrl;
            }

            var AuthorizeUrl = new Uri(Constants_Facebook.AuthorizeUrl);
            var AndroidRedirectUrl = new Uri(Constants_Facebook.AndroidRedirectUrl);
            var AccessTokenUrl = new Uri(Constants_Facebook.AccessTokenUrl);

            var authenticator = new OAuth2Authenticator(
                clientId,
                string.Empty,
                Constants_Facebook.Scope,
                AuthorizeUrl,
                AndroidRedirectUrl,
                AccessTokenUrl,
                null,
                true);

            authenticator.Completed += OnAuthCompleted_fb;

            AuthenticationState.Authenticator = authenticator;

            var presenter = new Xamarin.Auth.Presenters.OAuthLoginPresenter();
            presenter.Login(authenticator);
```

Activity in Android part :

```
[Activity(Label = "ActivityCustomUrlSchemeInterceptor", NoHistory = true, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop)]
[IntentFilter
    (
    actions: new[] { Intent.ActionView },
    Categories = new[]
            {
                Intent.CategoryDefault,
                Intent.CategoryBrowsable
            },
    DataScheme = "https",
    DataHost = "www.facebook.com",
    DataPath = "/connect/login_success.html"
    )]
```

On app, after login, i only see

```
Success , warning message about safety
```

So i think the problem is either in my intent filter declaration or in facebook part

anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

i think there is a problem in Xamarin.auth or on Facebook :

```
var authenticator = new OAuth2Authenticator(
            clientId,
            string.Empty,
            Constants_Facebook.Scope,
            AuthorizeUrl,
            AndroidRedirectUrl,
            AccessTokenUrl,
            null,
            false);
```

Using native UI doesn't work, without work.